# Why isn't the distinction between CPUs more ubiquitous?

Tags: cpu, executable, machine-code

I know that every program one writes has to eventually boil down to machine code - that's what compilers produce, that's what executable files consist of, and that's the only language that processors understand. I also know that different processors may have different instruction sets (I know 65c816 assembly, and I imagine it's vastly different from today's computers).

Here's what I'm not getting, though: If there exist different instruction sets, then *why do we not seem to have to care about that every time we use software*?

If a program was compiled for one particular CPU, it might not run on another - and yet, I never see notices like "Intel users download this version, AMD users download this one". I never have to even be aware of what CPU I'm on, every executable just seems to... work. The same goes for compilers, apparently - there isn't a separate version of, say, GCC, for every processor there is, right?

I'm aware that the differences in instruction sets are much more subtle than they used to be, but even then there should at least be a bit of a distinction. I'm wondering why there doesn't seem to be any.
What is it that I'm not understanding?

Comment: most popular modern computers (Intel/AMD) use very similar processor architectures https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86

Comment: If you were running an operating system, which is provided for multiple CPU architectures, you would need to care. For example, try running a x86/x64 PC Linux binary on Raspberry Pi, or vice versa, and see how it goes.

Comment: And yes, a compiler like *gcc* needs a different back-end for every CPU architecture they support (and, if it is compiling for different architecture than the one where the compiler runs, that is called *cross-compiling*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There actually are sometimes different versions for Intel/AMD. Even for different versions of Intel and/or AMD. That's not common (especially in the kind of software people usually use) because it's not user friendly (most people don't even know what a CPU is or does, let alone what kind they have exactly), so what often is that either the multiple versions are all in the same executable and selected at runtime, or a "least common denominator" sub-set of instructions is used (when performance is not really a concern). There are significant differences between AMD and Intel though, the most significant one is in which instruction sets they support. AMD always lags behind Intel in implementing Intels new instructions (new sets come out [regularly](http://www.10stripe.com/articles/timeline-x86-instruction-extensions.php)), and Intel usually does not implement AMDs extensions (AMD64 is the big exception (99% accepted by Intel, small changes made), also a couple of instructions here and there were borrowed, but XOP will never happen even though it's awesome, 3DNow! was never adopted by Intel). As an example of software that does *not* package the code for different "extended instruction sets" in the same executable, see y-cruncher.

To get back to the beginning though, for some (I can't name any off the top of my head, but I've seen it before) high performance software you may see different versions each specifically tailored to get maximum performance on one specific microarchitecture. For example, P4 (netburst) and Core2 are two very different beasts (that's mostly P4's fault for being crazy), even though Core2 is backwards compatible and could run the same code unmodified, that is not necessarily a good idea from a performance perspective.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Intel/AMD versions, because they use the same IS family: x86.
However, there are applications where you have to look out for different versions when you download them. There are still instruction sets that are quite different and might make a program act differently. For example if you have a PowerPC architecture and code a network based application on it, you can forget the little to big endian conversion, but if you compile the same code on x86, which is little endian, the application most likely will produce garbage on the network side.

There is also the difference in how many instructions there are, e.g. RISC vs CISC.

In the end there are a lot of differences to look for and in most programming languages you don't have to worry too much about them though, as the compiler/interpreter will handle most things for you. If you work lower lever then you have to know what you're doing on each architecture.

Also if you compile for ARM, you won't be able to run the program on any other machine, like your PC with x86. It will not work at all.
Because the op codes may/do differ, take the mov instruction, on x86 the op code is 0x88, on ARM it might be 0x13 etc.

Comment: So basically, the whole thing is a non-issue because almost all personal computers use the x86 family?

Answer (score 0):

The distinction is in fact quite dramatic. Except in the case of Intel vs. AMD. AMD makes their processors compatible with Intel machine code. On purpose of course.

Today there is a move to JIT compiling (Java, .NET, etc.). In this case, the executable file doesn't contain machine code. It contains a simple intermediate language that is compiled just before it is executed, in the machine code of the running processor. This allows the processor architecture to be completely opaque.

Comment: .exe file for java? :)

Answer (score 0):

AMD is an intel clone.  or vice versa depending on your view of the situation.  Either way, there is so much in common that programs can be compiled as to run on either (within reason, cant go back 10 years for example, cant make a 32bit processor understand 64 bit specific instructions).   Next step is the motherboards have to do similar things and they do, there maybe some intel or amd specific chip support items but then you get into generic peripherals that can be found on either platform or are widespread enough on one or the other platform that the operating systems and/or applications support them.